# Bluetooth programming in Linux - cross compiler issue

Tags: c, bluetooth, compiler-errors, cross-platform

I've installed

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```

to have bluetooth package in my environment.

Hence, using the following command can successfully compile the bluetooth code using gcc.

```
gcc -o bt bt.c -lbluetooth
```

However, when I tried to use the cross-compiler to compile the source code

```
$CC -o bt2 bt.c -lbluetooth
```

I got the fatal error:

```
fatal error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

Is there anything I've done wrong or I need to link this library to this cross-compiler ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess your cross compiler cames with a complete toolchain and SDK. Is this bluetooth package installed into your SDK?

Comment: @LPs you gave a good hint. I found the bluetooth.h in the SDK directory /lntel-quark-wrs-linux/usr/include/debug/bluez4-4.101-r3/bluez-4.101/lib/bluetooth.h --- is this the one you refer to ?

Comment: It seems it is but you must check that is the same header of the installed i386/x64 version on PC In case of the file is the right one you must change  your `#include` into your code.to match the path into your SDK.

Comment: And you must check that the same library is gave by your SDK. I mean that  e.g. `libBluetooth.so` have to be installed in `SDK /usr/lib` or `SDK /usr/local/lib`

Comment: @LPs thanks. would you mind moving your reply to answer so that I can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your cross compiler comes with a complete `toolchain` and `SDK`.

You must check that e.g. `libBluetooth.so` installed into your SDK under `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` folders and the correct header, as the one installed for `i386/x64` platform, is present into `SDK`.

In case of the `header` and `lib` exist you must change your `#include` into your code to match the path into your `SDK`.