# cross compile bluetooth C program(blueZ) for Android

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, cross-compiling, bluez

In order to run the bluetooth C program on my ubuntu desktop I installed the `libbluetooth-dev` using

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```

Then I compiled the code with

```
gcc -o simplescan simplescan.c -lbluetooth
```

and it executed just fine. However when I tried to cross compiled it for Android using

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o simplescan simplescan.c -lbluetooth
```

It gave me the error

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lbluetooth 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status​
```

I noticed there was similar post here: [Bluetooth programming in Linux - cross compiler issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736362/bluetooth-programming-in-linux-cross-compiler-issue)

But seems like it didn't give a solution, I am still confused how to install the `libbluetooth-dev` support for the cross compiler.

Comment: The answer does in fact give a solution. You should look at it again and read it more carefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth programming in Linux - cross compiler issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736362/bluetooth-programming-in-linux-cross-compiler-issue)

Comment: Probably your toolchain doesn't shipped with bluetooth development library. So you need to cross compile BlueZ first (with dependency) and cross compile with according sysroot.

Comment: Try compiling BlueZ for android. URL from google, http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_BlueZ_Bluetooth_tools_for_ARM

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link the libbluetooth library that was compiled for a different architecture. 
You need to build the libbluetooth library for the architecture your application will be build for.